# Chrome extensions. Как вернуть значение из chrome.cookies.get?

Tags: chrome-extension, firefox-extension

Из content script отправляется сообщение. В background стоит слушатель:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("from a content script:" + sender.tab.url);
        chrome.cookies.get({ url: sender.tab.url, name: "hello" }, function (cookie) {
        if (cookie) {
            sendResponse({answer: "yes"});
        }
        else {
            sendResponse({answer: "no"});
        }
        });
        console.log('Пришло cs: ', request);
    });
```

Как вы уже догадались sendResponse должен вернуть ответ в content script, но он его не возвращает. Подозреваю, что асинхронный запрос chrome.cookies.get не успевает вернуть значение, т.к. с точками останова всё работает нормально.

Поделитесь опытом, что можно сделать в данном случае.

p.S. Подозреваю, что вы отправите меня почитать ["Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0), но, к сожалению, у меня не получилось применить это к моему случаю =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай `return true;` в конце слушателя, тем самым Хром дождется выполнения асинхронного вызова.
[Ссылка на ответ на en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20077854/5398808).